# Static variables are not shared between threads when using Unity containers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unity-container

I have the following class

```
public static class EventHandlers
{
   public static readonly BlockingCollection<SignalCommands.Commands> CommandsQueue = new BlockingCollection<SignalCommands.Commands>();
}
```

where on a class instance A adding items and on class B taking items

Class A
`EventHandlers.CommandsQueue.Add(SignalCommands.Commands.CMD_CMN_START)`

Class B 
`EventHandlers.CommandsQueue.Take()`

When I run the code without the Unity containers, it work as it is supposed, meaning I a have producer on the one side and a consumer on the other side. When I switch to Unity ecosystem using DI it seams that a new Instace is created for each thread thus the instance of class B never gets the values added from calss A. Can someone explain the behavior and introduce a solution?

P.S. #1 I dont want to inject the BlockingCollection instance to the class B, I just want to share the static object between multiple threads.

Update:

```
public static class DependencyManager
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> _implementation = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => Initialize(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.PublicationOnly);

    public static IUnityContainer Current
    {
        get
        {
            return _implementation.Value;
        }
    }

    private static IUnityContainer Initialize()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initialize IoC");
        try
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().AddExtension(new Diagnostic());
            container.RegisterType<CommandHandler>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled, new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IPropertiesManager>()));

            container.RegisterSingleton<TradesSynchronizer>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IPropertiesManager>(), new ResolvedParameter<IConnectionService>(ConnectionType.DIRECT), new ResolvedParameter<ITradeService>(), new ResolvedParameter<JournalService>()));

            container.RegisterType<ITradeService, TradeService>(TypeLifetime.ContainerControlled, new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IPropertiesManager>(), new ResolvedParameter<IBootStrapper>(ConnectionType.PUMPING), new ResolvedParameter<ITickService>()));

            return container;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now in Entry Class (Application) I have the follwowing

The class which produces the signals
`Task.Run(() => DependencyManager.Current.Resolve<CommandHandler>().Start());`

The one who receives the signals
`Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).ContinueWith(t => DependencyManager.Current.Resolve<TradesSynchronizer>().Start()).ContinueWith(_task => Utils.LogException(_task, _logger));`

Here are my logs:

Log Format: Date|Level| ThreadId |Class|Message

```
2020/02/13 16:09:32.603|DEBUG|4|CommandHandler|Adding signal to queue ..
2020/02/13 16:09:32.603|DEBUG|4|CommandHandler|Adding signal to queue ..
2020/02/13 16:09:33.882|DEBUG|10|TradesSynchronizer|Total signals count 2
2020/02/13 16:09:33.883|DEBUG|10|TradeService|Summary Total signals count 0`
```

TradeService is injected to the TradesSynchronizer however as you can see both are running on the same thread 4.

Same call for both class is 
_logger.Debug("Total signals count " + EventHandlers.CommandsQueue.Count);

Note: There is not implementation for reading/take out signals from queue only writting to.

Comment: post your code with unity containers

Comment: Code posted! Assist is really appreciated!

Comment: Using static fields or properties to share state is a *bad* idea, DI or no. When using a DI container, the common way is to register the "service" that provides that state as a singleton service. In your code though, you aren't using Unity as a DI container at all

Comment: Where is `CommandsQueue` used anyway? In `CommandHandler`? It could be that `CommandHandler` has a problem. What happens when `Start()` is called multiple times for example.

Comment: In any case, .NET already provides high-level *non*blocking pub/sub implementations - the TPL DataFlow blocks available in all supported .NET versions and the newer System.Threading.Channel classes. Both can be used to create high speed processing pipelines. In fact DataFlow grew out of the Microsoft Robotics runtime

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos First of all thank you for you comments. The only place where I use recolve is in main where I want to start a banch of threads doing different things. The whole solution from there is based on DI of Unity. In addition Start is only called once in main there is no way to call Start() more than once.

Comment: Also regarding the static fields sharing is indeed a bad idea but in my case I just have one producer and multiple subscribers, where I don't want to inject an instance to each dependency for clean code sakes.

Comment: The code isn't clean, doesn't work and is hard enough to debug that you had to post a question at SO. There's no way to help without knowing how `CommandsQueue` is used, or what CommandHandler does. The one thing that's certain is that the out-of-the-box classes (Dataflow blocks, Channels) work without a problem. And Unity doesn't affect the runtime semantics - it won't affect how a static *field* behaves